# Finding all docs whose nested array contains at least two specific subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection `Project` with documents that look like the following :

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(...),
  name: "some name",
  members: [
    {
      user: ObjectId(...),
      joined: false,
      ...
    },
    {
      user: ObjectId(...),
      joined: true,
      ...
    },
    {
      user: ObjectId(...),
      joined: true,
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]
```

Given two `user` ids, I would like to query all the documents where `members` contains **at least both** users with `joined` equal to `true`. Additional members could be present, but the two must be present.
I have no clue what to do, especially with `$elemMatch`. Any idea ?

Intuitively, I would have done something like this :

```js
Project.find({
  members: {
    $elemMatch: [
      {
        user: firstId,
        joined: true
      },
      {
        user: secondId,
        joined: true
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $and over two $elemMatch clauses:

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.foo.insert({_id:1,members:[{a:1,joined:true},{a:2,joined:true}]})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.foo.insert({_id:2,members:[{a:1,joined:true},{a:2,joined:false}]})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.foo.find({$and:[{members:{$elemMatch:{a:1,joined:true}}},{members:{$elemMatch:{a:2,joined:true}}}]})
{ "_id" : 1, "members" : [ { "a" : 1, "joined" : true }, { "a" : 2, "joined" : true } ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    
    $addFields:{
        members:{
            $filter:{
                input:"$members",
                cond:{
                    $or:[
                        {
                            $and:[
                                {$eq:["$$this.user",ObjectId("5f49d0623c7e81bfcf37b8ed")]},
                                {$eq:["$$this.joined",true]}
                                ]
                        }
                        ,
                        {
                            $and:[
                                {$eq:["$$this.user",ObjectId("5f49d075d14cb1f5e2ff6a77")]},
                                {$eq:["$$this.joined",true]}
                                ]
                        }
                        ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hzGcZDZ2N0x)

Comment: Yep, that's what I wanted to avoid. Any alternative without aggregation ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
db.collection.find({
  "members.joined": true,
  "members.user": {
    $all: [
      3,
      4
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SBJNStSOyuB)